# Find the count of duplicate items in a C# List

Tags: c#, list

I am using List in C#. Code is as mentioned below:

TestCase.cs

```
 public class TestCase
{
    private string scenarioID;
    private string error;

    public string ScenarioID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.scenarioID;
        }
        set
        {
            this.scenarioID = value;
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return this.error;
        }
        set
        {
            this.error = value;
        }
    }

    public TestCase(string arg_scenarioName, string arg_error)
    {
        this.ScenarioID = arg_scenarioName;
        this.Error = arg_error;
    }
}
```

List I am createing is:

```
private List<TestCase> GetTestCases()
    {
        List<TestCase> scenarios = new List<TestCase>();
        TestCase scenario1 = new TestCase("Scenario1", string.Empty);
        TestCase scenario2 = new TestCase("Scenario2", string.Empty);
        TestCase scenario3 = new TestCase("Scenario1", string.Empty);
        TestCase scenario4 = new TestCase("Scenario4", string.Empty);
        TestCase scenario5 = new TestCase("Scenario1", string.Empty);
        TestCase scenario6 = new TestCase("Scenario6", string.Empty);
        TestCase scenario7 = new TestCase("Scenario7", string.Empty);

        scenarios.Add(scenario1);
        scenarios.Add(scenario2);
        scenarios.Add(scenario3);
        scenarios.Add(scenario4);
        scenarios.Add(scenario5);
        scenarios.Add(scenario6);
        scenarios.Add(scenario7);

        return scenarios;
    }
```

Now I am iterating through the list. I want to find the how many duplicate testcases are there in a list with same ScenarioID. Is there any way to solve it using Linq or any inbuilt method for List?

Regards,
Priyank

Comment: What is the answer in your example? 1, 2, or 3 (or other)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080538/c-sharp-determine-duplicate-in-list

Comment: Why do you need to count the duplicate items? (Curious)

Comment: Using linq, group by scenarioID and then count the size of each group.  Or create a Dictionary<string, int>, using scenarioID as the key and storing the count of the id as the value.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
var numberOfTestcasesWithDuplicates = 
    scenarios.GroupBy(x => x.ScenarioID).Count(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

Answer (score 8):

As a first idea:

```
int dupes = list.Count() - list.Distinct(aTestCaseComparer).Count();
```

Comment: @daryal - a better definition of equal (dupe) will be needed. As I tried to say, it's a rough sketch that solves the counting issue.

Comment: This will not work out of the box - you omitted the need to implement either a custom Equality comparer or override equality within OP's class

Comment: @broken - inserted a placeholder.

Answer (score 5):

To just get the *duplicate count*:

```
int duplicateCount = scenarios.GroupBy(x => x.ScenarioID)
                              .Sum(g => g.Count()-1);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var groups = scenarios.GroupBy(test => test.ScenarioID)
    .Where(group => group.Skip(1).Any());
```

That will give you a group for each ScenarioID that has more than one items.  The count of the groups is the number of duplicate groups, and the count of each group internally is the number of duplicates of that single item.

Additional note, the `.Skip(1).Any()` is there because a `.Count()` in the `Where` clause would need to iterate every single item just to find out that there is more than one.

Comment: `Skip(1).Any()` might be a better approach if you want to go that route

Comment: @BrokenGlass Yeah, both are constant time rather than O(n), but yours is indeed better; edited.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe

```
var result= GetTestCases()
            .GroupBy (x =>x.ScenarioID)
            .Select (x =>new{x.Key,nbrof=x.Count ()} );
```

Answer (score 1):

To get total number of duplicates, yet another:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>();
var result = scenarios.Count(x => !set.Add(x.ScenarioID));
```

To get distinct duplicates:

```
var result = scenarios.GroupBy(x => x.ScenarioID).Count(x => x.Skip(1).Any());
```