# Finding the same values C#

Tags: sorting

I'm just wondering what's the simplest way to find the same values? I am just the beginner, so I'm looking for the simplest way, without any vectors and etc..
For example, I need to sort Streets:

- 1street
- 2street
- 1street
- 3street

and the answer must be that "1street" is the most commonly named here.

Comment: Have a look a this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9909544/6729295

Comment: In your title, You are asking for Finding the same value and in you question you are asking for sorting

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `List<string>` that contains your items:

```
List<string> myList = PopulateList(...);  // fill the list with names
```

If you just want to sort the list, you can use `List.Sort`:

```
myList.Sort();
```

You could then go through the list with a loop to count up the duplicates and determine which is most frequent.

Or, you can group the items and then sort the grouping by count, descending, and take the first item.

```
var mostCommon = 
    myList.GroupBy(x => x)
          .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
          .First();
```

And then `mostCommon.Key` will tell you the most common item, and `mostCommon.Count()` will tell you how many items there are.

Or, if you wanted a list of `{name, count}`, ordered by count:

```
var groupedAndSorted =
    myList.GroupBy(x => x)
          .Select(x => new {Key=x.Key, Count=x.Count()})
          .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
          .ToList();
```