# Flag all but one duplicates in a list

Tags: c#, list, collections, duplicates

I have the list of objects of the following class,

```
class Invoice
{
   public int InvoiceNumber;
   public string CustomerName;
   public bool IsDupe;
}
```

The invoice numbers can be duplicate or there can even be a case of 4 invoices , all with the same number.

I need to set the IsDupe flag on all except one of the invoice object.
One approach is the brute force method of having a list of invoice numbers and comparing each one to flag. 
I have also tried this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410153/get-duplicates-from-c-sharp-listobject) .
Is there any better syntactical way to do it ? TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have a list of these elements, you can use LINQ and utilize `ForEach` extension:

```
List<Invoice> invoices = /* */;

invoices
    .GroupBy(inv => inv.InvoiceNumber)
    .ForEach(group => group.Skip(1).ForEach(notFirst => notFirst.IsDupe = true));
```

It groups invoices up by `InvoiceNumber`, and if a group contains more than one item, then it sets `IsDupe` to `true` for all except for the first one.

However, using `ForEach` seems to be non-LINQ-friendly and less readable for me.
It looks great with `foreach`:

```
foreach (var group in invoices.GroupBy(inv => inv.InvoiceNumber))
{
    foreach (var notFirstItem in group.Skip(1))
    {
        notFirstItem.IsDupe = true;
    }
}
```

Now, it is absolutely readable - take every group, take all items except for the first one, and mark as `IsDupe = true`.

Answer (score 5):

This works.

```
var invs = new List<Invoice> { new Invoice { InvoiceNumber = 1 }, 
                               new Invoice { InvoiceNumber = 1 }, 
                               new Invoice { InvoiceNumber = 1 },
                               new Invoice { InvoiceNumber = 2 }, 
                               new Invoice { InvoiceNumber = 3 }, 
                               new Invoice { InvoiceNumber = 3 } 
                             };

invs.ForEach(i => i.IsDupe = true);
invs.GroupBy (i => i.InvoiceNumber)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i => i.IsDupe = false);
```

Produces

```
1 null False 
1 null True 
1 null True 
2 null False 
3 null False 
3 null True
```

Alternatively, you could call the property `IsNotDupe` and take advantage of the fact that the boolean defaults to false (you can remove the first `ForEach`)