# Get subsequent element in list C#

Tags: c#, list, collision-detection

I have been asked to improve a given piece of code. The idea of the code is to take a list of objects, and with two foreach loops check if they collide. The code written in pseudo:

```
foreach (Entity object in objectList) 
    foreach (Entity object2 in objectList)
        if (object.collideWith(object2))
            Collision(object,object2)
```

For each object, it loops over each object - which is not efficient. Instead I should change it to "For each object, loop over every subsequent object". Im fairly new to C#, but this is how i imagened the soulution in pseudo:

```
foreach (Entity object in objectList) 
    if (object.collideWith(subsequent object))
        Collision(object, subsequent object)
```

This way, I'm only checking if an object collides with another once. But how do I get the "subsequent object" in my list?

Comment: I would suggest searching for "c# linq intersect"

Comment: I'm not quite sure how it would be useful in my case. Doesn't intersect take two lists and return the elements which are the same? I only have one list of objects.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547354/c-sharp-linq-find-duplicates-in-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve the code by eliminating the "lower half" of the cartesian product (provided that the collision relation is symmetric) as follows, using `for` loops instead of `foreach` loops.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < objectList.Count(); i++ )
{
    var iObj = objectList[i];
    for ( int j = i ; j < objectList.Count(); j++ )
    {
        var jObj = objectList[j];
        if ( iObj.collideWith(jObj) )
        {
            Collision( iObj, jObj );
        }
    }
}
```

This reduces the numbe rof collision checks roughly by a factor of 2. However, the runtime complexity is the same and the approach is difficult to implement with Linq.

Comment: you're initializing j = i in your second loop, so on each pass through the second loop there will be an unnecessary comparison of each object to itself

Comment: Excellent! This worked for me - however i added the following line:             if (!iObj.Equals(jObj) && !jObj.Equals(_player))                                                 This way the object don't compare to itself (not your fault since it wasn't part of my question). Thanks!

Comment: @JoeIrby Yes indeed, but I did this conciously as this comparison will also be done in the original question.

Comment: You'd probably be better off using the `Count` property rather than the `Count()` extension method.

Answer (score 2):

"For each object, loop over every subsequent object"

```
for (int i = 0; i < objectList.Count - 1; i++)
{
  for (int j = i+1; j < objectList.Count; j++)
  {
    var obj1 = objectList[i];
    var obj2 = objectList[j];

    if (obj1.collideWith(obj2))
      Collision(obj1, obj2);
  }
}
```