# c# change color of duplicates rows on datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

[Photo of datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcFrz.png)

i have this datagridview on picture above and "Joe" name is duplicate on it 
how can to highlight or change color to red for duplicates values like "Joe" by c#?
thanks:)

Comment: Show us your effort so far.

Comment: Clue, it has something to do with `CellFormatting` event and a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
    //using System.Linq;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rows = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Reverse().Skip(1);//ignore the last empty line
        var dupRos = rows.GroupBy(r => r.Cells["name"].Value.ToString())
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
        .SelectMany(r => r.ToList());
        foreach (var r in dupRos)
            r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        foreach (var r in rows.Except(dupRos))
            r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
```

Comment: Some explanation for your code? While the functionality of it is probably working (and beeing an easy task) understanding the code isnt. Specially cause LINQ is kinda special. I'd like to work with LINQ myself, but it seems that nobody that uses Linq likes to explain the code they use for answers.

Comment: the most important is `GroupBy` method, to find out those duplicate rows. then set each rows' color depending on whether it's duplicate. please check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547354/c-sharp-linq-find-duplicates-in-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547354/c-sharp-linq-find-duplicates-in-list)(and i realized my code can be simplier now!)