# Find duplicate values in dictionary of list c#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Dictionary `mapItemTidsets` is as follows:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> mapItemTidsets = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
```

And there are the following key and values:

**Key** **Value**

1 => 1,5,6

2 => 1,2,3,6,7

3 => 1,3,4,6

4 => 1,2,3,4,6,7

5 => 2,3,4,6,7

6 => 2,5,7

I want to specify the duplicate values in the comparison of multiple keys.

**Example 1 :**

Key = 1,3    => Output = (1,5,6) ∩ (1,3,4,6) = 1,6

**Example 2 :**

Key = 2,4,5  => Output = (1,2,3,6,7) ∩ (1,2,3,4,6,7) ∩ (2,3,4,6,7) = 2,3,6,7

Comment: have look under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547354/c-sharp-linq-find-duplicates-in-list

Comment: *I want to specify* -- that's not a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use method as follows

```
IEnumerable<int> GetDuplicates(IDictionary<int, List<int>> dict, IEnumerable<int> keysToLook)
{
    return dict.Keys
        .Intersect(keysToLook)
        .SelectMany(k => dict[k])
        .GroupBy(i => i)
        .Where(g => g.Count() == keysToLook.Count())
        .Select(g => g.Key)
        .ToArray();
}
```

to find duplicates in dictionary by specified set of keys to look.

Test to verify:

```
static void Tests()
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>()
    {
        { 1, new[] { 1, 5, 6 }.ToList() },
        { 2, new[] { 1, 2, 3, 6, 7 }.ToList()},
        { 3, new[] { 1, 3, 4, 6 }.ToList()},
        { 4, new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7 }.ToList()},
        { 5, new[] { 2, 3, 4, 6, 7 }.ToList()},
        { 6, new[] { 2, 5, 7 }.ToList()}
    };

    var expected1 = new[] { 1, 6 };
    var expected2 = new[] { 2, 3, 6, 7 };
    var result1 = GetDuplicates(dict, new[] { 1, 3 });
    var result2 = GetDuplicates(dict, new[] { 2, 4, 5 });
    Console.WriteLine(expected1.SequenceEqual(result1));
    Console.WriteLine(expected2.SequenceEqual(result2));
}
```

**Update**: The result can also be achieved with bit simpler form of linq:

```
IEnumerable<int> GetDuplicates(IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>> dict, IEnumerable<int> keysToLook)
{
    return dict.Keys
        .Intersect(keysToLook)
        .Select(k => dict[k])
        .Aggregate((p, n) => p.Intersect(n));
}
```

where the dictionary has more generic specialization (the type of values is denoted as `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>`). If `List<T>` however is still required inside the dictionary, the aggregation should be modified to work explicitly with `List`:

```
.Aggregate((p, n) => p.Intersect(n).ToList())
```

Comment: The output is not true, I used this command:  `List<int> B = new List<int>(); B.Add(2); B.Add(4); B.Add(5); IEnumerable<int> x = GetDuplicates(mapItemTidsets, B);` But the output obtained in X is equal to: 1,2,3,6,7,4

Comment: @solmazahamdi, yep, fixed the code.

Comment: thank you for your efforts. But the output is still not correct. output is : 1,3,6

Comment: @solmazahamdi, which keys combination is it for ?

Comment: intersect in the values that keys are given as input, such as example 2

Comment: @solmazahamdi, I've added test in the post to verify the correctness which works fine for me. Please specify explicitly which input values give you incorrect results.

Comment: You are right, Thanks for the patience and response