# How to check if item is already in list in repository?

Tags: c#

Ok, so there are a few excepotions here, I cannot use `List<Dvd> Dvds = _dvds.ReadAll();` in DvdController.cs and check to see if it contains the dvd info if dvd is already in the list. Even if I did do that, it does not work as I intended it to do. Even if I check to see if the info is in the list and try to stop it, it still adds it to a list. The Dvd.cs does increment the Id by one by the way. I would like to know what would be the solution to this?

**DvdController.cs**

```
...
private void CreateDvd() //Create
    {
        var myView = new DvdView();
        var dvdInfos = myView.GetNewDvdInfo();

        _dvds.Create(dvdInfos);
        DisplayDvds();
    }
...
```

**DvdRepository.cs**

```
public class DvdRepository
{
    private static List<Dvd> dvds = new List<Dvd>()
    {
        new Dvd("Batman", 2010, "Bruce", 4 ),
        new Dvd("Superman", 2009, "John", 4),
        new Dvd("Wonderwoman", 2012, "Omar", 4)
    };
    public Dvd Create(Dvd dvd)
    {
        if (dvds.Contains(dvd))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("duplicate"); //not working
        }
        else
            dvds.Add(dvd);

        return dvds.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == dvd.Id);
    }
    public List<Dvd> ReadAll()
    {
        return dvds;
    }
...
```

**Dvd.cs**

```
public class Dvd
    {
        public Dvd(string title, int releaseyear, string director, float rating)
        {
            Id = Interlocked.Increment(ref globalId);
            Title = title;
            ReleaseYear = releaseyear;
            Director = director;
            Rating = rating;
        }

        public static int globalId;
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }
        public string Director { get; set; }
        public float Rating { get; set; }
```

Comment: For `Contains` to work on the value instead of by reference you'll need to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in `Dvd`.  Alternatively you could do `if(dvds.Any(d => d.Id == dvd.Id))` if you just want to check for duplicate Ids.

Comment: @juharr you should put that as an answer, with the caveat that, if `Dvd` is a generated class (such as Entity Framework pocos), it will generate it as a `partial` class and he can provide his own `partial` class to override the Equals method.  As it's a generic list, it'll also need to implement `IEquatable<T>`.

Comment: Not checking for duplicate ids, mostly just title

Comment: @Moo-Juice It doesn't have to implement `IEquatable<T>`, but if you're going to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` you might was well implement it since the Default comparer will take advantage of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# LINQ find duplicates in List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547354/c-sharp-linq-find-duplicates-in-list)

Comment: You could also use another datatype than `List<Dvd>`. For example a `Dictionary<int, Dvd>` where the key (`int`) is the ID of the DVD will automatically ensure you do not have duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

Your check of `if (dvds.Contains(dvd))` is looking for that specific object reference. Unless you pass in the actual object that is in the list already, it won't work.

You need to check a unique identifying property of the `Dvd`. For this you would want to use the `.Any()` method.

```
if (dvds.Any(x => x.Title == dvd.Title))
```

Comment: Works ok, at least it doesnt duplicate.

Comment: @AlejandroH What else are you looking for it to do?

Comment: Ok let me post my Dvd class properties, but was expecting Title, ReleaseYear, Director, Rating as one duplicate but is a good answer.

Comment: @AlejandroH The concept doesn't change. You would just need to put all of those properties in the `.Any()` check.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that requires a bit more code upfront but will likely help in other scenarios in the future is to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods on the `Dvd` class. By default, objects use a reference comparison to determine equality. By overriding these methods, we can use our own logic to determine if two Dvds are equal.

In the example below, I'm using the fields `Title`, `ReleaseYear`, and `Director`, but you could add others as you see fit. I also implemented `IEquatable<Dvd>` because it's pretty simple (just requires adding an `Equals` method that takes an object of type `Dvd`) and it goes along well with the `object.Equals` implementation:

```
public class Dvd : IEquatable<Dvd>
{
    public Dvd(string title, int releaseyear, string director, float rating)
    {
        Id = Interlocked.Increment(ref globalId);
        Title = title;
        ReleaseYear = releaseyear;
        Director = director;
        Rating = rating;
    }

    public static int globalId;
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public float Rating { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Dvd other)
    {
        return other != null &&
               Title == other.Title &&
               ReleaseYear == other.ReleaseYear &&
               Director == other.Director;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Dvd);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ((Title?.GetHashCode() ?? 17) * 17 +
                ReleaseYear.GetHashCode()) * 17 +
               (Director?.GetHashCode() ?? 17);
    }
}
```

With these changes in place, we don't have to worry about remembering which fields we need to compare when evaluating two `Dvd` objects in a `Linq` query (and if we want to add more properties for comparison, we just do it in one place rather than searching throughout our code), and we can do things like `if (firstDvd.Equals(secondDvd)) { // do something if they're equal }` .

Now we can use the `Contains` method as defined in your original code. For example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var repo = new DvdRepository();
    repo.Create(new Dvd("Batman", 2010, "Bruce", 2));
}
```

Outputs to the console: `"duplicate"`

Comment: I am kind of curious what you are doing in `public override int GetHashCode()`, are you encrypting something?

Comment: @AlejandroH No, just generating a number for an instance of this class based on the fields used in the `Equals` method. `GetHashCode` should always return the same number for classes that are considered equal (though two instances that return the same hash code are not necessarily equal). See [Object.GetHashCode Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.8) for more info.