# How to return the amount of duplicate letters in a string

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a user's input so that I can return how many duplicate characters they have.

This is how I got the input

```
  Console.WriteLine("Input a word to reveal duplicate letters");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

For example, the code should return something like:

List of duplicate characters in String 'Programming'

g : 2

r : 2

m : 2

How do I find duplicate letters and count them in a string?

Comment: You need to try something! Its not that much complicated, defines step and go thorw it

Comment: I'm going to tell you two things, and you should be able to work out what to do: (1) `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`. (2) You can split an `IEnumerable<char>` into groups of the same char using [`Enumerable.GroupBy()`](https://www.dotnetperls.com/groupby)

Comment: kindly check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547354/c-sharp-linq-find-duplicates-in-list]

Comment: _exactly_ 2 as count? Or just an ordinary histogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can obtain this by using `System.Linq` GroupBy(), you going to group your string by character value and after filter the generated groups that have more than 1 values like so :

```
var word = "Hello World!";
var multipleChars = word.GroupBy(c => c).Where(group => group.Count() > 1);
foreach (var charGroup in multipleChars)
{
    Console.WriteLine(charGroup .Key + " : " + charGroup .Count());
}
```

Comment: what is "x" here? you mean ``word``?

Comment: @Grisgram yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

this will include case sensitivity as well as excluding non alphanumeric char

```
var sample = Console.ReadLine();
var letterCounter = sample.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit)
                    .GroupBy(char.ToLower)
                    .Select(counter => new { Letter = counter.Key, Counter = counter.Count() })
                    .Where(c=>c.Counter>1);

foreach (var counter in letterCounter){
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}", counter.Letter,counter.Counter));
}
```

Comment: Mind that `toLower` may not work for "non-western" characters, like the turquish "i".