# In C#, how do I check for duplicate elements inside of a list, then print the name of the duplicate element?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, compare

I'm trying to sort a list alphabetically, then once the list is sorted, print the name of any element in the list which occurred more than once.

Most google searches only address comparing separate lists. I know you can compare strings, and that list elements (in this case are strings), but I'm not sure how to compare these strings since they're in the list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Challenge5alphabeticalOrderSorting
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> fruit = new List<string>()
            {
                "apple",
                "mango",
                "mango",
                "orange",
                "blueberry",
                "blueberry"
            };

            fruit.Sort();
            foreach (string f in fruit)
                Console.WriteLine(f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use Linq, `GroupBy()` then `Select()` where `Count() > 1`

Comment: Compare `[i]` to `[i + 1]`.

Comment: ```fruit.GroupBy(name=>name, (k,g)=>new{
    Name=k,
    Count=g.Count()
})
.Where(g=>g.Count>1)
.OrderByDescending(g=>g.Count)
.Dump();
``` see: http://share.linqpad.net/m8to6t.linq

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# LINQ find duplicates in List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547354/c-sharp-linq-find-duplicates-in-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below prints the duplicated names, as OP wants (not the count or something else), using `GroupBy`, `Where` and `Count` methods

> print the name of any element in the list which occurred more than
>   once.

```cs
var groups = fruit.GroupBy(f => f).Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
foreach (var group in groups)
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
```