# How to get duplicates by attribute with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have my class HomeTeam

```
public class HomeTeam 
{
    public ID { get; set; }
    public string codeTeam { get; set; }
    public string codeNumber { get;set; }
}
```

I have my list of objects:

```
var listaFiltrada = new List<HomeTeam>();
```

I want get all items that have the same **codeTeam** and **codeNumber** parameters.

```
Sample:

ID     CodeTeam   CodeNumber
 1      B538       B2235
ID     CodeTeam   CodeNumber
 2      B538       B2235
ID     CodeTeam   CodeNumber
 3      B333       B235
```

I want filter list return Item with ID 1 and 2.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're happy to help, but we won't do all the work for you

Comment: This has an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547354/c-sharp-linq-find-duplicates-in-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# LINQ find duplicates in List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547354/c-sharp-linq-find-duplicates-in-list)

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson - It's not a duplicate. This is about getting duplicates by multiple properties. The question you've linked to is similar, but might be misleading because of the how the duplicates are determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suppose that the 2 linq expressions could be combined in one but i think this works

```
            var teams = new List<HomeTeam>()
            {
                new HomeTeam() {ID = 1, codeTeam = "B538", codeNumber = "B2235"},
                new HomeTeam() {ID = 2, codeTeam = "B538", codeNumber = "B2235"},
                new HomeTeam() {ID = 3, codeTeam = "B333", codeNumber = "B235"},
                new HomeTeam() {ID = 4, codeTeam = "B333", codeNumber = "B235"},
                new HomeTeam() {ID = 5, codeTeam = "B333", codeNumber = "B235"},
                new HomeTeam() {ID = 6, codeTeam = "B333", codeNumber = "B235333"},
                new HomeTeam() {ID = 7, codeTeam = "B3444433", codeNumber = "B23534433"}

            };

            var groupedData =
                (from t in teams
                    group t by new {t.codeTeam, t.codeNumber}
                    into grp
                    where grp.Count() > 1
                    select new
                    {
                        grp.Key.codeTeam,
                        grp.Key.codeNumber,
                        Count = grp.Count()
                    }).ToList();

            var ids = from team in teams
                join grp in groupedData on new {team.codeNumber, team.codeTeam} equals new
                    {grp.codeNumber, grp.codeTeam}
                select new
                {
                    ID = team.ID
                };

            foreach (var id in ids)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(id.ID);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

this gives back a list with lists of duplicate items

```
var dups = listaFiltrada.Select(list => new HomeTeam()
        {
            ID = list.ID,
            CodeTeam = list.CodeTeam,
            CodeNumber = list.CodeNumber
        }).GroupBy(x => new { x.CodeNumber, x.CodeTeam })
        .Where(x => x.Count() > 1).ToArray();
```