# Check if there is an object with the same property value in list c# using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

### I have a list of objects and I want to check if there is objects with the same property values:

> **Level** is an object, that means levels of a house and has a property called *elevation*.

> *listOflevels* is a list of my object Level

I would like to know if in my list(listOflevels) there is two or more levels with the same elevation.

> Ex.: If I have one level with level.elevation = 3 and another one with level.elevation = 3, then the method should return true

I tried this way, but I wonder if there is a better way

```
foreach (Level level in listOflevels)
    {
        double levelElevation = level.Elevation;
        foreach (Level level2 in listOflevels)
        {
            if ((level2.Name != level.Name && level2.Elevation == levelElevation)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Can LINQ be used to improve this?

Many Thanks

Comment: Linq can improve the readability, but not performance. Look for `GroupBy` for example. The code you show is broken and will always return `true` if there is at least one element in `listOFLevels`. You'd need to check that `level2 != level` to find duplicates.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547354/c-sharp-linq-find-duplicates-in-list

Comment: after looking at your code, if It put in my words are you just trying to find whether the list that you are processing contains more than one of the value that is being compared?

Comment: `return listOflevels.GroupBy(l => l.Elevation).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);` this will do the equivalent using linq

Comment: @RenéVogt i just updated the code

Comment: @IbramReda though the result is correct, this is slower than the original code. Depending on what critieria OP is trying to "improve" (speed/memory/readability) this may be the correct or wrong answer.

Comment: @AbhinavPandey Yes!

Comment: @IbramReda this worked perfectaly! i was trying improve readability.

Comment: @RenéVogt yes, you are completely right. I did not say it is faster or answer the question, i just mention linq implementation because I thought the author search for it not for faster code because he did not mention any speed/ size issue

Comment: @RodrigoMatos Your update should be equivalent to this `return listOflevels.DistinctBy(l=>l.Name).GroupBy(l => l.Elevation).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);`